# Conditional regex expression

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex which validates that a string contains only numbers and is between 10 and 11 characters in length.

```
^[0-9]{10,11}$
```

However, if the string has a length of 11, I need to validate that the first character is a 1. If the length of the string is 10, no further validation is necessary.

examples of valid strings

```
3455558899

15554445555
```

example of an invalid string

```
25554445555

85554445555
```

Is this possible with regex? BTW, this regex will be used in a Java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with an optional match of `1` at start and then match next 10 digits:

```
^1?\d{10}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xt5I9e/1)

This will make this regex match 11 digits when first digit is `1` or it will match 10 digits.

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `1?`: Optionally match 1 at start
- `\d{10}`: Match exact 10 digits
- `$`: End

In Java use following String to construct your regex:

```
String re = "^1?\\d{10}$";
```

Comment: That works beautifully! Thanks, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If this is a numeric value, it's easier to convert to Long and then compare the value instead of regex.

```
String x = {your value};
Long i = Long.valueOf(x);
if(i <= 19999999999L) return true;
```

Comment: Interesting solution